# How do you take input separated by space in a single line in C?

Tags: c

I was attempting the [CodeChef](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodeChef) contest today where I came across this problem. I managed to do the code, but there's one error that I don’t know how to take all inputs in a single line separated by space. I checked thousands of answers on Stack Overflow, but I still didn’t get it. How can I fix this problem?

[image]

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int t, n, a, b, c, x, y, z;
    //printf("No. of test cases\n");
    scanf("%d", &t);
    for(int i=0; i<t; i++)
    {
       //printf("Enter three inputs\n");
       scanf("%d\t%d\t%d", &a, &b, &c);
    }

    x = a + b;
    y = b + c;
    z = a + c;
    if(x>y && x>z)
    {
        printf("%d", x);
    }
    else if(y>a && y>z)
    {
      printf("%d", y);
    }
    else
    {
      printf("%d", z);
    }
}
```

Comment: In respect to the reading, your code should work. What you need is to do more things inside the loop ... `for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) { scanf("%d\t%d\t%d", &a, &b, &c); /* more things here, for example: */ printf("read %d and %d and %d\n", a, b, c); }`

Comment: With `scanf("%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c);`or with `scanf("%d", &a); scanf("%d", &b); scanf("%d", &c);` This function (with these specifiers) doesn't *care* whether they are on the same or different lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same and is not a big deal.

Just enter your first input and instead of pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you press <kbd>Space</kbd>. Then enter your second input, press <kbd>Space</kbd> again, enter the third input, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It will definitely work.

Answer (score 1):

I will show you two programs and then may be you see a way to read the values in a controlled way.

`scanf()` is controlled by the mask, the thing like `"%d\t%d\t%d"` in your code. And `scanf()` has the notion of white space, treating spaces and tabs and newlines as same thing. These sometimes makes a mess when reading keyboard input, because `scanf()` refuses to end and keeps reading trying to satisfy the supplied input mask. [See the first example program].

Fact is that these functions were written to consume tabular data, like **CSV files** --- Hence the name: **scan f**ormatted input. But `stdin` with a keyboard with 105 keys are not formatted input: The user can key anything in.

**Always test the return of scanf()**

`scanf()` returns a negative value for error, or the number of items read. In your case, it can return 0, 1, 2 or 3: there are three fields to be read in `"%d\t%d\t%d"`

#### Example 1

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int A, B, C;
    int res;
    do
    {
        printf("\n==> Enter up to 3 integer numbers, separated by spaces: ");
        res = scanf("%d %d %d", &A, &B, &C);
        switch (res)
        {
            case 0:
                printf("\nscanf() read no numbers\n");
                break;
            case 1:
                printf("scanf() read a single value, A = %d\n", A);
                break;
            case 2:
                printf(
                    "scanf() read two values, A = %d, B = %d\n", A, B);
                break;
            case 3:  // Fall-through
            default:
                printf(
                    "scanf() read all 3 values, A = %d, B = %d, C = "
                    "%d\n",
                    A, B, C);
                break;
        };  // switch()

    }   while ( res != 0);
    return 0;
}
```

This code uses `scanf()` on `stdin` as usual.

#### Some results from example 1

```
==> Enter up to 3 integer numbers, separated by spaces: 1 2 3
scanf() read all 3 values, A = 1, B = 2, C = 3
```

All good when the numbers come as expected...

```
==> Enter up to 3 integer numbers, separated by spaces: 1 2



3
```

But now `scanf()` reads 1 and 2, but the user entered a few newlines, that `scanf()` skips like white space and will forever until read a letter or the final digit

And note this one:

```
==> Enter up to 3 integer numbers, separated by spaces: 1 end
scanf() read a single value, A = 1

==> Enter up to 3 integer numbers, separated by spaces:
scanf() read no numbers
```

The user entered `1 end`. As soon as the `e` is read `scanf()` returns 1 and A is set to 1, of course. But then the next call has the `end` letters and the newline to read, so the next call of `scanf()` reads these letters, returns `0` and the program ends.

This is the kind of outcome that surprise many beginners and even a few professionals sometimes.

And these is hard to control.

For these reason many times is better to read the whole line by other means, and use `sscanf()` to consume the data, as in example 2. The idea is that all data in the line is consumed, and `sscanf()` parses the data from memory.

I believe that the example is ok to understand.

#### Example 2

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int A, B, C;
    int res;

    printf("Enter up to 3 integer numbers, separated by spaces or ENTER to exit: ");

    char line[100] = {0};
    char* p = line;
    // read whole line, up to the possible '\n'
    p = fgets( line,100,stdin);
    if ( p[0] == '\n') return 0; // input empty
    do
    {
        res = sscanf(line, "%d %d %d", &A, &B, &C);
        switch (res)
        {
            case 0:
                printf("scanf() read no numbers\n");
                break;
            case 1:
                printf("scanf() read a single value, A = %d\n", A);
                break;
            case 2:
                printf(
                    "scanf() read two values, A = %d, B = %d\n", A, B);
                break;
            case 3:  // fall thru
            default:
                printf(
                    "scanf() read all 3 values, A = %d, B = %d, C = "
                    "%d\n",
                    A, B, C);
                break;
        };  // switch()
        printf("Enter up to 3 integer numbers, separated by spaces or ENTER to exit: ");
        p = fgets( line,100,stdin); // next line
    if ( p[0] == '\n') return 0; // input empty

    }   while ( res != 0 );
    return 0;
}
```

#### Output for example 2

```
Enter up to 3 integer numbers, separated by spaces or ENTER to exit: 1
scanf() read a single value, A = 1
Enter up to 3 integer numbers, separated by spaces or ENTER to exit: 1 2
scanf() read two values, A = 1, B = 2
Enter up to 3 integer numbers, separated by spaces or ENTER to exit: 1 2 3
scanf() read all 3 values, A = 1, B = 2, C = 3
Enter up to 3 integer numbers, separated by spaces or ENTER to exit: 1 2 end
scanf() read two values, A = 1, B = 2
Enter up to 3 integer numbers, separated by spaces or ENTER to exit: end
scanf() read no numbers
Enter up to 3 integer numbers, separated by spaces or ENTER to exit:
```

And things are a bit easier to control.